# Fibration with contractible total space

Tags: homotopy-theory, fibration

Let $F \to E \to B$ be a fibration, and suppose $E$ is contractible. Then the long exact sequence of homotopy groups shows that $F$ has the same homotopy groups as the loop space $\Omega B$. Is it true that $F$ and $\Omega B$ are homotopy equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if they are CW complexes, this is a corollary of this theorem of Whitehead.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem

Comment: Thanks, but what about when the spaces are not CW complexes? Also, for CW complexes how do you construct the mapping $\Omega B \to F$?

Comment: The idea of the map is, given a loop $I \to B$, use the lifting property of fibrations to get a path $I\to E$ such that $I\to E\to B$ is the loop. The value at the end point gives you an element of $F$.